# custom form update in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, error-handling

i try to update the custom form, for user new entry and user update the same form is used. in submit code i use if else for update and submit, it show an error " string indices must be integers, not str "

views.py:-

```
def applicationvalue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.method['usubmit'] == 'new':
            getappid = request.POST['appid']
            getjobtitle = request.POST['jobtitle']
            getodesk = request.POST['odeskid']
            getspecification = request.POST['clientspecification']
            getnotes = request.POST['notes']
            request.session['getappid'] = getappid
            getintable = applicationform(user_id = request.user.id , app_id = getappid, job_title = getjobtitle, odesk_id = getodesk, client_specification = getspecification, job_type = request.POST['jobtype'], notes = getnotes)
            getintable.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tableview/')

        else:
            request.method['usubmit'] == 'Update'
            saveapplid = request.POST['appid']
            savejobtitle = request.POST['jobtitle']
            saveodesk = request.POST['odeskid']
            savespecification = request.POST['clientspecification']
            savenotes = request.POST['notes']

            saveapp = applicationform.objects.get(app_id = saveapplid)
            saveapp.job_title = savejobtitle
            saveapp.odesk_id = saveodesk
            saveapp.user_specification = savespecification
            saveapp.notes = savenotes
            saveapp.save()  
            return HttpResponse(1)
#       return HttpResponseRedirect('/tableview/')

    else:
        return render_to_response('registration/applicationform.html')
```

when this code run than it display an error 
"  string indices must be integers, not str  "

Comment: Can you show us the *full* traceback, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.method` is a string (you just tested if it is equal to `"POST"` in the first `if` statement)!

Did you meant to test against `request.POST['usubmit']` instead?

The line:

```
if request.method['usubmit'] == 'new':
```

will throw an error, but perhaps you wanted:

```
if request.POST['usubmit'] == 'new':
```

instead. Moreover, the lines:

```
else:
    request.method['usubmit'] == 'Update'
```

don't do what you think they do. You probably wanted to *test* if `usubmit` is equal to `'Update'` for the second block:

```
elif request.POST['usubmit'] == 'Update':
```